# Setting up Sablecc in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, sablecc

I have followed the steps mentioned in the link: [Setting up sablecc in Eclipse](http://web.archive.org/web/20090318023544/http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~sethhetu/rooms/Tutorials/EclipseAndSableCC.html)
to install scablecc. I am trying to do step 9 mentioned in the link but I get the Error:Could not find or load main class.
Can any one guide me how to set up sable cc in eclipse. Are there any other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I also following same way which is mentioned in the link. when i was set-up, there is small issue in javaw.exe. so I set up location as '...software/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/java' . It works for me.[image]

Comment: Hello. In step 10 in the link it says that "You should get a whole bunch of console text explaining what SableCC's doing and after refresh your project's listing in the Package Explorer, there should be several new folders just recently created by SableCC".  I get some text displayed in console but there are no folders created in my Package Explorer. Did u get any folders displayed.

Comment: yep some of folders created